# Quicktype (iOS 8 Predictive Keyboard) does not display text highlight correctly when UITextView is at an angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uikeyboard, quicktypebar

My app has a UITextView that displays text at an angle.  This text can be edited by the user.  Everything about the control works and displays correctly except that the misspelled word highlighting doesn't display rotated.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?
Here's how it looks:

[image: Rotated UITextView with Quicktype spelling error highlighted]

Comment: Make the `UITextView` a child of a standard `UIView`, and rotate the `UIView`? And file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Why isn't that an answer? It's a great suggestion and non-obvious.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Because I didn't actually try it. I was waiting for feedback from the OP.

Comment: I'm already applying the rotation to a parent UIView.